# how to style the parent component depends on child component in angular?

Tags: angular

I am removing the padding of the parent component in its child component

This my component structure. Taken from the browser developer tool.

[image]

I have changed the padding of nb-layout-column (marked as blue in the above image) from the child component ngx-home-page.

**in ngx-home-page scss**

```
::ng-deep
  .nb-theme-default
     nb-layout
     .layout
     .layout-container
     .content
     .columns
     nb-layout-column {
     padding: 0;
   }
```

it is working fine for the nb-layout-column, when it has child ngx-home-page.

**issue is**

The style applied to the nb-layout-column after leaving the ngx-home-page(style is applying to other pages, but i have styles in ngx-home-page).

**i need the following**

case:1 while viewing ngx-home-page

```
<nb-layout-column>//it should have padding 0
 <ngx-home-page>
 </ngx-home-page>
</nb-layout-column>
```

case:2 while viewing other-pages

```
<nb-layout-column>//it should have default padding
 <other-page>
 </other-page>
</nb-layout-column>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Comment: You can set the padding (or use margin) in the child component instead. Or use margin there. Changing the parent based on the child could make your life unnecessarily complicated. There's some other approaches as well, but I would try to avoid sharing the state.

Comment: @Tr1monster No.